# ThinkingSphinx throws 'wrong constant name' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using ThinkingSphinx on Rails 4.0.0 to search through customer records. It works a lot of the time but now it throws this error:

`wrong constant name "\u008B­\u0089~\u008FöV"`

with the constant name varying depending on what is searched for. The search term is escaped etc and alphanumeric only.

Comment: Try upgrading ThinkingSphinx.   Which version are you using and with what kind of database?

Comment: Latest ThinkingSphinx / MySQL. However, I may have solved it. I say may as I restarted the server which could've also done it. I changed the encoding type in `development.sphinx.conf` to one that matched the fields I was searching

Comment: If you found the solution post it as an answer and accept it, please.

Comment: I will do, but I'm unsure if it has solved it just yet so I'll wait a bit and see before I do